# Forgotten term in the covariant form of $\mathcal{N}=4$ supersymmetric self-dual Yang-Mills theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills

For $\mathcal{N}=4$ supersymmetric self-dual Yang-Mills theory, the lightcone formulation reads:
$$
\int d^{4} x \ d^{4} \theta 
\left(
\frac{1}{2} V \Box V +
\frac{1}{3} V [\partial_{+} V, \partial_{\bar{z}} V]
\right) 
$$
Where $x^{+} = x^{0} + x^{3}$ and $x^{\bar{z}} = x^{1} - i x^{2}$ are the lightcone coordinates.
And $\theta$'s are the odd coordinates in the lightcone Mandelstam supersymmetric formulation.
And $V$ is the chiral superfield:
$$
V = \partial_{+}^{-1} A + \theta_I  \partial_{+}^{-1} \psi^{I} + 
\frac{1}{2} \theta_I \theta_J \phi^{I J} + \ldots
$$

Self-dual supersymmetric Yang-Mills action is actually a truncation of the full SYM action to the quadratic term and a triple vertex of definite chirality, as shown here https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9606061. By definite chirality I mean, that in the SYM there is a triple vertex with net chirality equal to 1, it involves following combination of fields:
$$
g^{-} g^{+} g^{+}, \lambda^{+} \lambda^{+} \phi, g^{+} \lambda^{+} \lambda^{-} \ldots
$$
Here $g^{\pm}$ denotes the gluon of the helicity +1 and -1 correspondingly,
and $\lambda^{\pm}$ fermion of helicity $\pm 1/2$.

There is a vertex in the SYM, involving fields, with the chiralities summing to $-1$. The self-dual theory has only the first vertex.

The covariant formulation the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9205075 reads:
$$
\int d^{4} x \ d^{4} \theta 
\left(
G^{\dot{\alpha} \dot{\beta}}
F_{\dot{\alpha} \dot{\beta}} +
\bar{\psi}^{I \dot{\alpha}} \nabla_{\dot{\alpha} \alpha} \psi^{I \alpha} +
\phi^{I J} \Box \phi_{I J} + 
\phi_{I J} \psi^{\alpha} \psi_{\alpha} 
\right) 
$$
From this expression I cannot see, how can one obtain the term :
$$
\phi \ \phi \ g^{+} 
$$
Because the scalar field seems to be interacting only via Yukawa interaction with fermions.

Presumably, there is an abuse with notation, and the $\Box$ is not an ordinary Laplacian operator, but something else, involving the covariant derivative : $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + [, A_\mu]$. The most apparent guess is:
$$
D_{\mu} \phi \ D^{\mu} \phi
$$
However, it has a term of $4$th order : $[A_\mu, \phi] [A_\mu, \phi]$, whereas we have only a cubic vertex. Another guess is:
$$
D_{\mu} \phi \ \partial^{\mu} \phi
$$
Here there is only a quadratic and cubic term, but this term looks somehow unnatural.